# Quality Current Free UDK Tutorials?

Tags: level-design, udk, unreal

I'm just getting started with the UDK, with experience in Unity, and would like a good tutorial series about getting to know my way around the basics of level design and a touch on programming. I have found some basic tutorials on level creation, but they are pretty old, and would like to know more.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would say this question is too broad and off topic for this site, but since there is one definitive answer to your question I'll give it:
[Google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=udk+tutorials&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

That being said I like these http://www.worldofleveldesign.com/categories/cat_udk.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have definitely done my Googling, and found a few things (outdated, like I said), but that's why I posted here. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Keavon Here are UDK tutorials on google for the past year...https://www.google.com/#q=udk+tutorials&hl=en&prmd=imvnsfd&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ei=Ey09T6_WIsK62gWOk7WgCA&sqi=2&ved=0CAwQpwUoBg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=63aabadeeb3cd353&biw=1280&bih=648

Answer (score 2):

[Eat3d](http://eat3d.com) has a many high quality UDK tutorials then anybody else. Gnomon has 2 good tutorials on [level creation](http://www.thegnomonworkshop.com/store/product/694/) and [material](http://www.thegnomonworkshop.com/store/product/849/Unreal-Development-Kit%3A-Materials).

Raven67854 on Moddb had created [huge number of UDK tutorial](http://www.moddb.com/forum/thread/udk-tutorials) on some very interesting topic that the commercial trainings doesn't cover. like , Fracture.

Before buying any try [these tutorial](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VideoTutorials.html) first. These are from 3dbuzz and now they are **freely** available on UDN. Also check out other tutorials from [3dBuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_videonav.php?fid=56797c0cd321ddc111e9059535cb3f24).

As always google and look into youtube for specific topic. Dont forget about, [UDK forum](http://forums.epicgames.com/forums/366-UDK). Its  very active.

Hope this helps you to have a good start!

Comment: Thanks for the great tips and links! I won't be buying any tutorials, but I'll definitely check out the free ones! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try checking out the youtube channel thenewboston, he went into quite a bit of content on using UDK. http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston